# (Angular) How to find a string value in an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, service, authentication

So i want to find a string value that comes from a html input inside an array, i'm working in angular 5 and i'm using a service file inside a component

**My code**

**login.component.ts**

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  userData = [];

  constructor(private router: Router, private usersList: OperationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersList.usersData.subscribe(getData => {
      this.userData = getData;
    });
  }

  login(login: NgForm) {

    if (login.value.userfield === this.userData) {
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
    }
  }
}
```

**operation.service.ts**

```
export class OperationService {

  constructor() {}

  private users = new BehaviorSubject<any>([
    {
      name: 'admin',
      password: 'lol'
    }
  ]);

  usersData = this.users.asObservable();

}
```

i tried some ways like:

```
this.userData.find(x => x.username == login.value.userfield )
```

or

```
this.userData.indexOf(login.value.userfield)
```

or

```
login.value.userfield === this.userData
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(this.userData)
```

but this still not work, is there a different option to do this? Am i losing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have name only not username,

```
this.userData.find(x => x.name === login.value.userfield )
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Can you tell how can i use only a password for an specific user? i mean, if i have two or more users the find will find the user and password but i can put the password of any user in the array

Comment: use and this.userData.find(x => x.name === login.value.userfield && x.password == login.value.passwordfield );